# How do I check for vue js compilation errors before trying to serve it?

Tags: vue.js, npm, compiler-errors

I've just lost a frustrating amount of time trying to work out why `npm run serve` was hanging when attempting to run my vue js app. Eventually, I tracked it down to one error in a vue file I made, it took me a long time to work this out since the issue manifests itself in a way that the console window just hangs.

Is there some other way developers can get a more descriptive error list from vue js prior to attempting to run/build?

Comment: Not sure what build tool you're using at present but it might be worth looking at https://eslint.vuejs.org/ or https://cli.vuejs.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I find the most useful and essential tools to be (I use VS Code as "IDE")

- [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur): includes syntax-highlighting, snippets, linter (error checking), auto completition, etc.
- [Vue.js devtools (for chrome)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon): Not sure about other browsers, but this is incredibly useful for chrome. Let's you see what's really going on with vue.js' components, the store, etc ([screenshot from the chrome store page](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/gP43uJZR8VGzLCtyOx2T5q4qcMq79yZhynf3M4a2SEzCA7KKVAY6DPeD7_JWZlu60xLPMqKW=w640-h400-e365)).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I use VS code too so i will give Vetur a go.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ np, glad it helped